# CS50 plurality - unable to print if there are too many winners

Tags: c, cs50

In plurality prblm, I managed to update votes for each candidate, my code can print the one winner, but still stuck if they are many winners .
help by hints or clues, not the whole solution.
Thanks in advance.

```
void print_winner(void)
{
    int v = 0; //maximum number of votes
    string w; //winner of the election
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (v <= candidates[i].votes)
        {
            v = candidates[i].votes;
        }
    }
    

    for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
    {
        if (candidates[j].votes == v)
        {
            w = candidates[j].name;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", w);
    return;
}
```

Comment: _"prblm"_? Do you mean _problem_?

Comment: The `printf` is outside any loops, so it executes just once. Instead of assigning to `w`, which can, of course, hold only a single value, print the name(s)  right there.

Comment: When votes are tied, there are no winners, only re-election.

Comment: that's what am i looking for, how to print if there are many winners.

Comment: Move the `printf` after the `w =` line?

Answer (score 0):

Change your second `for` loop to this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
{
    if (candidates[j].votes == v)
    {
        w = candidates[j].name;
        printf("%s\n", w);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate it into two for loops, if you have them together the first loop will run only through the first candidate with more than 1 vote and print it. Since it has not checked the others. That loops must finish and go through the whole set to actually find the max number of votes.

Answer (score 0):

I am also on the same problem with you for around 2 or 3 days now. But I think I found out how to print if there are multiple winners.

First, I have a variable to store the highest votes and initialized it to 0. Then I tried comparing the candidates[i].votes against the current highest vote.

Then, I assigned the new value of the highest vote with the candidates vote until the loop finds someone who is higher than the previous one.

Lastly, I looped again through all the candidates and checks each candidates votes if they are equal to the highest vote. If yes, then their names should be printed. This solved my problem in printing 2 or more winners.